# C# WPF Poker Game: How to make AI act like thinking?

Tags: c#, wpf

I´d like to make my AI opponent in the 1vs1 Poker Game "think" for a few seconds but I have no idea how to stop all actions while only a timer bar, or something that indicates AI thinking, is working.

I tried Thread.Sleep but I might have used it somehow wrong, because it kind of "crashed" the screen, maybe there still is a way to use it.

Basically, at first, I´d just like the code to do that every time I click a button (either Bet, Fold or Check/Call) then AI takes a few seconds to respond before he makes the decision.

Comment: It sounds like your call to Thread.Sleep is on the same thread which deals with UI. This at least explains the freezing effect you are seeing. You'll need another thread in one form or another, e.g. BackgroundWorker or some such

Answer (score 1):

Have you AI run in an async Task that will allow the UI thread to still update.

Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx for the basics.